# busybox httpd cgi doesn't print "return"

Tags: apache, cgi, executable, busybox, cgi-bin

Please help, I can't find the solution

Situation. I have busybox httpd server. In cgi-bin folder is an cgi-executable, which sends to client formatted text by printf command.

Problem is that the text format should look like a column, but client receives only a string. Despite the fact that in "printf" I use "\n" and "(char) 13". 
Another words executable doesn't return "return" symbol

I wrote following

```
for (i=0; i<4;i++)
 printf ("%9.8g%c\n",  lTemp[i]*dTemp[i], (char) 13 );
```

Answer (score 0):

The text that is sent from your CGI program to the web client is treated as HTML text, not plain text.
When HTML is processed for display in the browser, newline and carriage return (what you simply call "return") characters are ignored.

To cause the displayed text to perform a line break, the [HTML break tag](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_br.asp),  "< br />" should be inserted into the output string:

```
printf("%9.8g <br />\r\n", lTemp[i] * dTemp[i]);
```

The use of newlines and whitespace in the text that your CGI programs generates will have little bearing on the actual HTML page that gets displayed.  Use newlines and whitespace to format the HTML so that the source is readable, and use HTML tags to control the displayed text in the client's browser.

BTW
Using a numeric constant and a character conversion in a **printf** is not the preferred method of outputting a carriage-return character.
Use the defined escape sequence `\r` in the format.